# Solving a matrix differential equation using Runge-Kutta methods

Tags: control-theory, runge-kutta-methods

I could not find a control systems forum on stack exchange and so I am doing this here.
Is it possible to solve the state space variable form of a system $\dot{x}=A\,x + B\,u$ using any order of Runge-Kutta method, and if so can anyone please tell me the method

Comment: What do you want to solve for, $x$, as in a discretization method or $u$, as in a feedback control law?

Comment: Solve for x, the system's state trajectory

Comment: So using a fixed time step Runge-Kutta method for discretization?

Comment: yes, I would like to know how to do that for an lti system, then extrapolate to an lpv system

Answer (score 7):

Runge-Kutta methods considers the problem $\dot{x}=f(t,x)$ with $x(t_0)=x_0$ and wants to find $x(t)$ at $t=t_0+n\,h$ for $n=1,2,3,...$. In your case $f(t,x)=A\,x+B\,u$, so you have choose how to interpret $u$ as a function of time. Often $u$ is also only sampled every $h$ time units, so two options would be to assume $u$ to be constant between sample steps (zero order hold), or perform linear interpolation (first order hold). If $u$ is know continuously, then you can directly evaluate $u(t)$ at the give sub time steps of the Runge-Kutta method.

For example when using [the fourth order Runge-Kutta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_methods#The_Runge%E2%80%93Kutta_method) with zero order hold, using $x_n=x(t_0+n\,h)$ and $u_n=u(t_0+n\,h)$, you get

\begin{align}
x_{n+1}&=x_n+\frac{1}{6}\left(k_1+2\,k_2+2\,k_3+k_4\right) \\
k_1&=h\left(A\,x_n+B\,u_n\right) \\
k_2&=h\left(A\,(x_n+k_1/2)+B\,u_n\right)\\
k_3&=h\left(A\,(x_n+k_2/2)+B\,u_n\right)\\
k_4&=h\left(A\,(x_n+k_3)+B\,u_n\right)\\
\end{align}

Substituting these equations into each other gives

$$
x_{n+1} = \left(I + h\,A + \frac{h^2}{2!}A^2 + \frac{h^3}{3!}A^3 + \frac{h^4}{4!}A^4\right) x_n + \left(h\,I + \frac{h^2}{2}A + \frac{h^3}{3!}A^2 + \frac{h^4}{4!}A^3\right)B\,u_n
$$

which is just the fourth order approximation of the [zero order hold discretization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discretization#Discretization_of_linear_state_space_models), which can be expressed as

\begin{align}
x_{n+1} &= e^{A\,h} x_n + A^{-1} (e^{A\,h} - I)B\,u_n \\
e^{A\,h} & = \sum_{i=0}^\infty \frac{1}{i!}(A\,h)^i
\end{align}

Similarly one would obtain a fourth order approximation of the first order hold discretization when using first order hold for $u$. So when $u$ is sampled every $h$ time units and the system is LTI then using Runge-Kutta would just be an approximation of known discetization methods and you might as well use those methods instead. However if the sample frequency is sufficiently high compared to the system dynamics, then the difference between Runge-Kutta and the discetization methods should become negligible. If $u(t)$ is known at all time then Runge-Kutta might give more accurate results then the other mentioned discetization methods. And for LPV or LTV systems Runge-Kutta discetization should work as well, as long as the sample frequency is high enough.

Comment: So I presume step response can be done the same way, also is it Cali us

Comment: Sorry for that, I was intending to ask whether it is valid that for LPV systems, we change the parameters values of A matrix every time step, and continue to apply the same formulae of fourth order approximation

Comment: @user601753 Do you know how the parameters vary over time, so for the RK4 method also at the midpoint between time steps?

Comment: I am testing the scenario of sinusoidal perturbations on the system parameters for various frequencies, so yes, the parameter values can be determined

Comment: @user601753 Then it should work, provided that the sample frequency is sufficiently higher then the frequency of the sinusoidal parameter, say roughly at least ten times higher.

Comment: What if I have non deterministic perturbations, how then can I simulate stop response of the system using numerical methods?