# Numerical integration of differential equation in state-space form

Tags: numerical-methods, dynamical-systems, control-theory, runge-kutta-methods, eulers-method

I'm using numerical integration methods like Explicit/Implicit Euler, Runge-Kutta to solve a system of linear ordinary differential equations in state-space representation $\dot{x}=A\,x + B\,u$. I have already done some basic calculations with these methods as a system of differential equations and in matrix form. I have found this question [Solving a matrix differential equation using Runge-Kutta methods](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2946737/solving-a-matrix-differential-equation-using-runge-kutta-methods) with a great answer. But I want to go more deeply into the theory.  Can anyone recommend a textbook or paper that explains these numerical methods in combination with state-space representation? I'm doing a time simulation of an electric circuit in Matlab script.

Comment: It mostly depends on what software you will be using to solve the system, as a lot of authors base their books around what works best for a given software. I would suggest using google scholar and including your software as a keyword. If you are at university or school also check their online library as you can often access books for free and they may recommend ones related to your course.

Comment: Thanks, @Henry Lee for your reply. I'm mainly interested in mathematical formulation and theory. When I know the math, I can then apply it to Matlab, Python, C/C++, or some other programming language or software.

Comment: if $u=u(x)$ then it is just a non-linear first order ode which is fairly simple in matlab, which has lots of built-in ode solvers. As long as you know initial or boundary conditions you can use these. If $u$ is a second variable it is a little trickier

Comment: Here is a comparison of the built-in ode solvers: https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/math/choose-an-ode-solver.html